# WCF Tracing log message is set to false, but there is still a trace output being generated

Tags: wcf, trace

I have the following configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="false" logKnownPii="false" logMalformedMessages="false" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" maxMessagesToLog="250000000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="262144000">
    <filters>
      <clear />
    </filters>
  </messageLogging>
  <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />
</diagnostics>
```

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Off, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="RollingDateXmlWriterTraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Off">
    <listeners>
      <add name="RollingDateXmlWriterTraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <!--<add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Temp\Logs\MainService.svclog" />-->
  <add name="RollingDateXmlWriterTraceListener" type="XXX.Common.Listeners.RollingDateXmlWriterTraceListener, XXX.Common" traceOutputOptions="None" initializeData="C:\Temp\Logs\MainService.{yyyyMMdd}.svclog" />
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true" />
```

I have set false to all of the logMessage attributes, but i still get the svclog file. Do I miss something?

Comment: You can simply comment or remove the listeners and sharedlisteners.

Comment: I know and this is how it is implemented now - commented. I was thinking if it is possible to do it using settings in the configuration.

Comment: There are some configurations that can do it, see more here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411221/wcf-tracing-switchvalue-is-off-yet-there-is-still-a-trace-output-being-generated

I also think your question is duplicated with that, isn't it?

Comment: It is similar but not exactly. I read that if I set logMalformedMessages="false" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false", this should stop logging. However, it doesn't.